# How to allow chroot-ed user both SSH and SFTP access

Tags: unix, chroot

I currently know how to allow a user **either** SSH **or** sFTP by editing:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

This lets the user login with SSH but not SFTP:

```bash
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Match group chrootedgroup
      ChrootDirectory /var/chroot/
```

This lets the user use sFTP but not SSH:

```c
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group chrootedgroup
      ChrootDirectory /var/chroot/
      ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

How can I make a user capable of logging in using **both**?

Comment: Wondering if you found a solution to acheive this?

Comment: This link https://www.tecmint.com/restrict-ssh-user-to-directory-using-chrooted-jail/ helped immensely to setup ssh-only or sftp-only chroot-ed user, but not both. To achieve both ssh and sftp in chroot-ed case, comment out the "ForceCommand internal-sftp". Then, replace the default "Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server" with '''Subsystem sftp internal-sftp", that's it! (see Henry Luo's answer below)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same problem, figured out through the help of
https://www.howtoforge.com/restricting-users-to-sftp-plus-setting-up-chrooted-ssh-sftp-debian-squeeze#-enabling-chrooted-ssh
Solution mentioned in the last few lines of the section 'Enabling Chrooted SSH'.

To support both SSH and SFTP, your configuration should be:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group chrootedgroup
      ChrootDirectory /var/chroot/
```

Comment: Take note that before writing the line '''Subsystem sftp internal-sftp", make sure to comment out the default "Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server".